# jquery: getting contents of #content field on post page

Tags: posts, jquery, content

I managed to get the #content field html with this jquery call:

```
jQuery("#content").html()
```

This seems to be failing though on "Add New Post" pages. Any tips on how to get the contents of the #content div?

Cheers

Comment: It seems there is no div#content within the `Add New Post` page!

Comment: I can see it `<div id='editorcontainer'><textarea rows='20' class='theEditor' cols='40' name='content' tabindex='2' id='content'></textarea></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The div `#editorcontainer` contains a regular textarea `#content` and an iframe `#content_ifr`.

The `#content` is filled with the saved contents of the post when the page loads. This means that any live edits of the content won't be returned when calling `jQuery("#content").html()`. For the same reason, you get an empty string in the case of a new post.

Where you really need to look for the live updated contents is in the iframe, which is used by the WYSIWYG editor. Here's how:

```
jQuery('#content_ifr').contents().find('#tinymce').html();
```

Also see: [jquery/javascript: accessing contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe).

Comment: Much appreciated. Noticed this works as well `tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent(content)` Wonder if there is a universal solution, as there is a CK Editor plugin as well http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ckeditor-for-wordpress/

Comment: @giorgio79: doesn't work for me. Returns `NULL`. Also if I try `tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent(content)` it gets an error saying `activeEditor` is `null` do i have to enqueue any script?

Answer (score 0):

my code works fine in this form:

```
tinyMCE.triggerSave();
txt = $('#myTextarea')
    .contents()
    .find('#tinymce')
    .html()
    .replace('&lt;br data-mce-bogus="1"&gt;', '')
;
if (console && console.log) console.log(txt);
```